# Textillate w/ jQuery not functioning. Uncaught TypeError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

OK, I feel like I have tried everything. I know there are a lot of similar questions but I am not super familiar with Javascript so the other answers I have read go way over my head. I am getting:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`  when trying to run the script for [Textillate](https://github.com/jschr/textillate):

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <?php include('head.php'); ?>


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css?version=1.4" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lettering.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.textillate.js" async></script> 

<script>
$(function() {
             $('.txt').textillate({ 
  in: { effect: 'rollIn' },
  out: { effect: 'foldUnfold', sync: true },
  loop: true

         });
 </script>
```

I have loaded in the latest version of jQuery, animate.css, textillate.js and lettering.js in the `<head>` as instructed by the documentation.

My HTML is this:

```
<h1 class="txt" data-in-effect="rollIn">text</h1>
```

Can someone please tell what is wrong in simplest terms and how to fix this error?

It is probably something obvious that I am missing but like I said I am a noob. The live demo can be found here: www.thekdesignco.com/new/

Comment: This usually happens when jQuery is not included or is not found at the location you have specified.  Do you know if you have included jQuery?

Comment: Have you linked `jquery` before the script shown in question..?

Comment: could you edit the post and show us the whole of your `<head>`?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being included... You can check it in resources of your browser developer toolbar

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect everything in the head tag...

Comment: Remove the `async` attribute from the script-tags. Then the scripts will be loaded in the right order.

Comment: Remove the `async` attribute in the script-tags. Then the scripts will be loaded in right order.

Comment: I tried removing the tags but now I have another error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < &
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. Would it help to send you the link to where I have the site live currently?

Comment: You may include the link in your question. And *do not remove the complete tags*, only remove **async**.

Comment: Have update with a link to an example. And I retained the script tag but just removed async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue was: the `async`-attributes in the sript-tags. With `async` the HTML-parser does'nt wait until the scripts are loaded. So the DOM is ready first and the `$(function() {})` is executed before jQuery is there.

Second issue: the function in your last script is not properly closed. It has to look like:

```
$(function() {
     $('.txt').textillate({ 
         in: { effect: 'rollIn' },
         out: { effect: 'foldUnfold', sync: true },
         loop: true
     });
});
```

Please fix it now.

Third issue: somewhere is a `<` too much or at the wrong place. It seems to be a problem in the`jquery.textillate.js`-file. When I find it I'll update this answer.

**EDIT**: The file in `js/jquery.textillate.js` **is not jquery.textillate.js** but some unknown HTML-file. Clean up your `js-folder`.

Comment: DOH! Goodness, thank you for your patience! I'm not sure how the wrong file got in there...

Comment: @KristinP Glad I could help. Next time use your console (F12). The error-messages there leads you to the scripts and lines where something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery.noconflict();

will solve the issue.

Comment: I am not sure how to integrate this. Could you be more specific? Sorry I am not fluent in Javascript.